# problem with casting a custon list in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, deprecated

I want ger rid of the deprecated message but in any way I changed code project gone wrong.

```
if (json['images'] != null) {
images = new List<Images>();
List<Images> images = new List<Images>();

json['images'].forEach((v) {
images.add(new Images.fromJson(v));
});
}
class Images {
String src;

Images({this.src});
    
Images.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
src = json['src'].toString();
}
}
```

I tried:

```
List<Images> images = new List<Images>();
images = new List<Images>();
List<Images> images = []..length = 500;
```

Comment: What is the error message? Your code is wrong on lines 2 and 3. You asset `json['images']` for not null but you use `json['src']` can be null too

Comment: Please provide your json object and the error message

Comment: how is your 'images' json data structure look like?

Comment: OMG. Line 3 actually wasn't in the main codes.

Comment: I have no error but when run that code (when line 2 commented and line 3 id active), I have this:

Comment: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you are trying to parse a JSON of a collection of images, right? If that is the case, you are not doing it properly. Here is the solution:

```dart
class Image {
  String src;

  const Image({ this.src });

  factory Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Image(src: json['src']);
  }
}

// First, we cast the json as a dynamic list
final list = json['images'] as List;

// Then iterate over it using map to create a new list
final images = list.map((json) => Image.fromJson(json)).toList();

// There you have it
print(images.runtimeType); // output: List<Image>

// You can also do a loop with it
images.forEach((image) => print(image.src));
```

You might want to do a null check before doing these, just to be safe.